# Cordova - Capture video and retrieve base64 data

Tags: javascript, cordova, encoding, base64

I am using phonegap to record a video and I am wanting to save the base64 data-encoded string. So far I have tried this..

```
function captureSuccess(mediaFiles) {
    var i, path, len;
    path = mediaFiles[0];
    win(path);
}

function win(file) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function (evt) {
        console.log("read success");
        console.log(evt.target.result);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file); 
};

function captureError(error) {
    navigator.notification.alert('Error code: ' + error.code, null, 'Capture Error');
}

function captureVideo() {
    navigator.device.capture.captureVideo(captureSuccess, captureError, {limit: 1});
}
```

I have used readAsDataURL as specified in the [documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileReader). The output of `evt.target.result` is `"data:video/mp4;base64,"` **but there isn't any encoded data after the filetype.**

Is there anything else I need to add in order to get the full base64 data of the video?

I am really struggling to find anything that can help me. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: hey Pooshonk, have you found any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

```
var b64toBlobAlt = function(dataURI, contentType) {
  var ab, byteString, i, ia;
  byteString = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);
  ab = new ArrayBuffer(byteString.length);
  ia = new Uint8Array(ab);
  i = 0;
  while (i < byteString.length) {
    ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
    i++;
  }
  return new Blob([ab], {
    type: contentType
  });
};
var path = mediaFiles[0].fullPath;

window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(path, function(fileEntry) {
  return fileEntry.file(function(data) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function(e) {
      var blob = b64toBlobAlt(e.target.result, 'video/mp4');
      if (blob) {
         // do whatever you want with blob
        });
      }
    };
    return reader.readAsDataURL(data);
  });
});
```

Comment: Hi kevohagan, please consider adding an explanation as to how your code works.

Comment: @kevohagan my code stuck in `reader.readAsDataURL(data)`. It doesn't giving any error but not coming in `onloadend` function.

Comment: @VivekJain It is likely that you received an error. You can listen for errors using `reader.onerror = function (error) {}`